# Bootstrap classes for laravel 5 form submit button

Tags: laravel-5

Below is the part of input field and submit button.[image]

I want to increase the width of submit button as the input field using bootstrap.

Here is my code.

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
 {!! Form::label('Event Photo') !!}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
 <input type='file' name='photo' id ='photo' class ='form-control'/>
 </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    {!! Form::submit('Add', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>
```

But the button size can't get increased like that. Where am I wrong? How should I solve that?

Comment: Have you tried using `btn-lg` for example? You can see that [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes) `btn-block` is also a class that may aid your effort.

Comment: @m-cooper I have added that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The `array()` part of your form allows you to pass in any other parameters that you want.

Just as you are using it to define the class, you can use it to define the `style`:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    {!! Form::submit('Add', array('class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'style' => 'width:50px;)) !!}
</div>
```

Just change `50px` to whatever width you want to use.

Comment: I need to solve that using bootstrap. Because after I assign the style attribute to the array, when re-sizing the browser button size will not changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the class `btn-lg` will work.

You can find that in the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes)